# Proof that an observer cannot be in two places at once

Tags: special-relativity

If you went at light speed, you would literally and instantly teleport from the sun to the Earth. Any slower would create the perception of time. In other words, we appear frozen to the light (or observer going at c).

Still, the light can never appear frozen to us. Its speed is always the same, so that if we left the sun at 0.999c, the light that left the sun and appears outside our spaceship’s window going in our direction is also going at c.

That sounds like it’s breaking physics, but since everything’s relative, it doesn’t. If you can be in two places at once - that is, observe yourself on the spaceship and on earth, wouldn't it break relativity?

Comment: It takes over 8 mins in average for light to get from the Sun to the Earth. What do you mean by "you would literally and instantly teleport from the sun to the Earth."? That you would go faster than light?

Comment: @user54826 See Arpad's answer below: "For light, the emission at the sun and the absorption on Earth happens instantly. The photon does not experience time as we do, the speed of the photon in the time dimension is 0."

Comment: It seems that the question is "Is there any proof that an observer cannot see themselves in their coordinate frame in special relativity?" This can be shown by considering the light cone of an event along the world-path of the observer. Real observers follow time-like curves, and will hence never touch the light-cone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No object with rest mass can travel at c. Everything is relative to c, the speed of light in vacuum (when measured locally).

For an observer on Earth, it takes 8 minutes for a photon to reach Earth. That is why an observer on Earth (observer who has rest mass) experiences time.

A photon does not have a reference frame. You cannot say from the view of the photon.

What you could say, is that you could try to look at it the way around, that everything is relative to the speed of light. You have to slow down from speed c, and to do that, you need to gain rest mass, that is how you can experience time.

For light, the emission at the sun and the absorption on Earth happens instantly. The photon does not experience time as we do, the speed of the photon in the time dimension is 0.

To imagine how it is to go that fast in space, you could chech what a neutrino experiences when traveling from the sun to Earth. From the neutrino's frame, time passes really slow (compared to clocks on Earth). The neutrino will see and experience this travel as it only takes very little time on the neutrino's own clock as per SR.

For an observer on Earth, the neutrino still seems to arrive in a little more then 8 minutes.

What you are referring to, that the photon is at the two places at the same time, is called a lightlike worldline. For the photon, the place of emission in the sun and the place of absorption in spacetime is zero distance.

For the neutrino, the same distance in spacetime is not zero distance. it is called a timelike worldline.

The answer to your question is that at the same time at different places means that the neutrino cannot be at different places at the same time because its worldline is timelike. In spacetime, the photon's worldline is lightlike, and for the photon the spacetime distance is zero between the emission and absorption. You cannot say that the neutrino is at the same time at different places. You could though view it as if the photon was experiencing time so that it would travel a zero distance (in spacetime) from emission to absorption.